# Open Office: How to disable image link updates

Tags: images, openoffice-writer

I'm writing a user manual to a card game and there is a looot of linked images. Open Office is working so slow because every time I flip to a page with linked images it starts to update them.

Is it possible to tell Open Office to NOT update the links until I tell it to do so?
I would like it to display the same snapshot it showed the last time I initiated link update.

I'm using Open Office v3.3.0

// Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Libreoffice and OpenOffice use this path:

Tools -> Options -> Libre/ OpenOffice writer -> General -> Update-update links when loading.

You can select one of the following options:

- Always
- On request
- Never

As shown [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/office_guides/openoffice_writer_user_guide/openoffice_guide_Updating_links.html).

For greater speed with loading images you could:

From office help-edit links, have Graphics On/Off icon on the Tools bar activated, no graphics are displayed - only empty frames as placeholders. This would increase the speed of loading the images and hold the link.

To increase [speed](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=43944):

1. Tools-> options-> load/save-> general, uncheck load printer settings with document
2. Tools-> options-> office-> memory-> graphic's cache, you can increase the cache size

For office, memory per object. Cache for inserted objects == number of objects. As for stopping newly created links being updated over old is probably not able to be done.

---

In Apache OpenOffice 4.1.10, on Mac, these options are now in OpenOffice -> Preferences...

Comment: Are you sure this is for Image links as well and not only document links? Because it was already set to "On Request" and when I scroll the document The placeholders are empty, only with the link text in them. The whole system is very slow until it finally loads the picture. Then it is fast until I scroll some more pages and everything repeats. Is there a cache size that can be increased or something? The images are only 1MB each .PNG

Comment: @max can you un-click feilds in options-> updates-see help-> index-> feilds-. auto update